# Fibonacci for letters

Tags: c, char, c-strings, fibonacci, function-definition

I was programming a code for a case provided by my university. It was about making a Fibonacci function, but for letters. For example, if `f(0)` -> `a`, `f(1)` -> `b`, then `f(2)` -> `ba`, and so on. I was halfway until finish when I found a problem that I cannot solve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void fib(char bank[][700], char result[700], int n) {
    char temp[700];
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i > 2) {
            strcpy(bank[i - 1], result);
        }
        for (int k = 0; bank[i - 1][k] != 0; k++) {
            result[k] = bank[i - 1][k];
        }
        strcat(result, bank[i - 2]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int cases = 0;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    getchar();
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= cases; i++) {
        int n = 0; char first[5] = {};
        char wordBank[][700] = {{},{}};
        char result[700] = "#";
        scanf("%d %c %c", &n, &first[0], &first[1]);
        getchar();
        wordBank[0][0] = first[0];
        wordBank[1][0] = first[1];
        
        if (n == 0) {
            printf("Case #%d: %c\n", i, first[0]);
        } else if (n == 1) {
            printf("Case #%d: %c\n", i, first[1]);
        } else if (n > 1) {
            fib(wordBank, result, n);
            printf("Case #%d: %s\n", i, result);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

So the example input is:

```
3
2 a b
3 a b
4 a b
```

`3` on line 1 is the number of test cases,
`2` on line 2 is the result of `f(n)`,
`a` and `b` on line 2 in `f(0)` and `f(1)`,

The output would be:

```
Case #1: ba
Case #2: bab
Case #3: babba
```

The problem occur when I try to input `n` more than `3`. I try to use `usleep` function to kind of slow down the process because I think that's the source of the problem. `usleep` only help me until a few more n range.

The `f(0)` and `f(1)` are guaranteed 1 letter, so it can't be 'ab' for `f(0)` or `f(1)` or any other more than 1 letter combination for both `f(0)` and `f(1)`.

Comment: `char wordBank[][700] = {{},{}};` defines `wordBank` as an array of **only two** arrays of 700 characters each (all 1400 characters are `'\0'`). Try `char wordBank[700][700];`

Comment: "and so on" is not a good description. Maybe this is meant as a binary output, replacing "0" with "a" and "1" with "b"? If so, do a conventional Fibonacci  computation, convert the output into a binary String and replace "0,1" to "a,b" accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you are telling enough of the logic for us to help you.  Ie:  if f(0) = a, f(1) = b ... OK, I'm still with you .... then f(2) = ba.  (??) ...  Then is f(3) = cba ??   This is very puzzling to me.   At least I can tell you that you can only do 3 inputs per loop because your scanf("%d %c %c" ,...)   is coded to take exactly 3 inputs.

Comment: f(0) = a; f(1) = b; f(2) = f(1) + f(0) = ba; f(3) = f(2) + f(1) = bab; f(4) = f(3) + f(2) = babba; that the pattern?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in java, but you are on C/C++. Using C it is easier not to convert to String.class but just use the bits of the integer result to get "a"s and "b"s by looking at the least significant bit and then shift right.

Comment: Re "*i don't know how to reply to your comment directly*", Not your fault. Answers shouldn't be provided as comments. What you'd normally do is check the mark next to Answer. But noone posted an Answer.

Comment: @ruwby Can you elaborate why is the array first declared with 5 elements char first[5] = {};?

Comment: @ruwby And in my opinion your function fib has a wrong declaration void fib(char bank[][700], char result[700], int n){. I think it should be declared like char * fib( size_t n, char c1, char c2 ); because it depends on read characters as for example 2 a b. The user can enter 2 @ # instead of 2 a b.

Comment: @ruwby: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.  Once you gain enough reputation, you will be able to show your gratitude by upvoting any answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

`char wordBank[][700] = {{},{}};` defines wordBank as an array of **only two** arrays of 700 characters each (all 1400 characters are `'\0'`).

Try defining a larger array

```
char wordBank[100][700] = {0};
```

See https://ideone.com/W9guSZ

Answer (score 0):

For starters this header:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

is redundant because neither declaration from the header is used in the program.

The function `main` without parameters shall be declared like:

```
int main( void )
```

Using the function `getchar` as for example in this line:

```
scanf("%d", &cases); getchar();
```

is also redundant. You should remove calls of `getchar`.

It is unclear why you are using the magic number `700` in the program.

Within the function the array `temp`:

```
char temp[700];
```

is not used.

You declared the array `wordBank`:

```
char wordBank[][700] = {{},{}};
```

only with two elements. But within the function there can be an access to memory outside the array due to the loops:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    if(i > 2){
        strcpy(bank[i - 1], result);
    }
    for(int k = 0; bank[i - 1][k] != 0; k++){
        result[k] = bank[i - 1][k];
    }
    strcat(result, bank[i - 2]);
}
```

when `n` is greater than `2` that results in undefined behavior.

According to the assignment the function should build a new string.

It should be declared like:

```
char * fib( size_t n, char c1, char c2 );
```

using arbitraty two initial characters. The caller of the function should pass the characters to the function.

I would define the function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * fib( size_t n, char c1, char c2 )
{
    size_t first = 0;
    size_t second = 1;

    size_t length = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        length += first;
        second += first;
        first = second - first;
    }

    char *result = calloc( length + 1, 1 );

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        size_t previous_size = 0;
        size_t next_size = 0;

        char *p = result;

        size_t i = 0;

        do
        {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 0:
                *p = c1;
                break;

            case 1:
                *p = c2;
                break;

            case 2:
                *p++ = c2;
                *p++ = c1;
                next_size = 1;
                previous_size = 1;
                break;

            case 3:
                *p++ = c2;
                break;

            default:
                memcpy( p, result, previous_size );
                p += previous_size;
                break;
            }

            next_size += previous_size;
            previous_size = next_size - previous_size;
        } while ( i++ < n);
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char *s = fib( i, 'a', 'b');
        if ( s != NULL ) puts( s );
        free( s );
    }
}
```

The program output is:

```
a
b
ba
bab
babba
babbabab
babbababbabba
babbababbabbababbabab
babbababbabbababbababbabbababbabba
babbababbabbababbababbabbababbabbababbababbabbababbabab
```